# Respalda mi proyecto app

Tags: android-studio

¿Como se puede reespaldar un proyecto?

Puedo copiar la carpeta desde su origen y llevarla a una USB; no existe otra manera al menos en la nube?

Comment: Puedes exportar tu proyecto desde `File > Export to Zip File` seleccionar la carpeta de destino y ya tendrás una copia de tu proyecto. Para abrir nuevamente el proyecto se debe descomprimir el archivo .zip he importar el proyecto desde Android Studio en la opción `Open an existing Android Studio Project`. Si deseas almacenar tu proyecto en la nube como respaldo puedes utilizar un gestor de versiones como `git` para almacenar tu código en los servicios de GitHub o Gitlab, con estos servicios puedes llevar un historial de tu código y un respaldo en la nube.

Comment: Puedes copiar el proyecto, también puedes subirlo a la nube y descargarlo, usar un versionador o exportar el proyecto como .zip , desde el menú ve a File -> Export to Zip File..., ya trataste abrir el proyecto en otra pc? trataste algún método anteriormente, probablemente encontraras más preguntas al abrir el proyecto. Me parece que tu pregunta debe ser más especifica, revisa por favor [ask].